# Set a one line powershell for sleep and hibernate to turn off

Tags: powershell, command, sleep, hibernation

```
powershell -Command "& {c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0; c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe - change - monitor - timeout - dc 0; c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe - change - disk - timeout - ac 0; c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe - change - disk - timeout - dc 0; c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe - change - standby - timeout - ac 0; c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe - change - standby - timeout - dc 0; c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe - change - hibernate - timeout - ac 0; c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe - change - hibernate - timeout - dc 0 }"
```

How would I write this code correctly? I want to set multiple power options at once to turn off hibernate and sleep modes.

Comment: Hi, why one line ? And why PowerShell ? These commands are very efficient by themselves :).

Comment: What do you mean "correctly"? Does it not already do exactly what you want?

Comment: I'm agreeing with the first comment: why do this in PowerShell? It's been my experience that (unless you're familiar with the parsing engine) normal .exe commands (such as powercfg.exe) WORK in PowerShell, but there are some conventions that don't work so well either, and if you're not doing any form of checking / handling, it's not even worth using the shell for this. If, however, you'd like to continue using PowerShell (there's no need to in this case, but you certainly can), and want to have a single line, you could convert that single line to a script, and then just call the script.

Comment: I just used powershell because it always seems to go faster than command prompt but either one would really do

Comment: I wanted to make sure I was doing my syntax right on here.

Comment: Or if you could direct me to the best direction on how do multiple commands in one line.

Comment: Which commands/syntax don't work as well in Powershell?  Thanks for your input.

Comment: That you all for your input!  I appreciate your help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var newProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        newProcessInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
        newProcessInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; // hide processes as they happen
        newProcessInfo.Verb = "runas"; // run as administrator
        newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command ""c:\power\powercfg.bat"""; //you can use the -noexit to troubleshoot and see the commands
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newProcessInfo);
```

Batch file (`c:\power\powercfg.bat`):

```
@echo off
powercfg.exe -x -monitor-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -monitor-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -disk-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -disk-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -standby-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -standby-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -hibernate-timeout-dc 0
```

This worked best.

Comment: Why use C# to launch PowerShell to execute a batch file?

Comment: Because you are making a user interface for other techs....  Powershell is the most powerful and it makes the programming consistent for other types of advanced commands.

Comment: Irrelevant, but I fail to understand why `powercfg.exe -x -disk-timeout-ac` should set the same setting for all drives. Any idea if it is possible to have different configurations per drive?

Comment: I would guess in your actual drivers under Device Manager.  I have seen sleep settings in there, but it depended on the drive/brand.

Comment: Sometimes people make interfaces in C#, that's what I was using this for.

Answer (score 0):

loved the answer this worked like a charm thanks for the reply
I mean this answer

loved the answer this worked like a charm thanks for the reply
I mean this answer

```
@echo off
powercfg.exe -x -monitor-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -monitor-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -disk-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -disk-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -standby-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -standby-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -hibernate-timeout-dc 0
```

Comment: No need to repeat the correct answer, just upvote & accept